# Laravel Spark Composer Update only changes vendor folder

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-spark

So, I am not totally well versed in composer and Laravel spark and it's been awhile since I have done this so forgive me if this is a silly question.

I updated Laravel Spark from version 1 to version 2 and then 3. I need to make use of the afterLoginRedirectTo function which was not available in version 1. Composer update ran fine and I can see the function in the file named "ManagesAppOptions.php." However, it does not appear that any of my files outside of the vendor/Laravel/Spark folder have been changed. I ran composer install and that didn't do anything either.

Am I missing the point here and I just need to push the changes to the vendor folder to the production side?

Do I need to run gulp or something to rebuild those files in my app folder? Are they not changing because Spark thinks that I manually changed them already? If so, how do I force that to update?

Comment: Can you post your composer.json file and the expected versions of the packages?

Comment: When you update a system like Spark, they would only update the background files. They don't want to mess up a system you already have in place. On the website you should find update instructions depending on which version you're coming from.